# How to remove FadeIn, while a Tab button is activated in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I think its quite easy, but I just cant get it:

How to remove FadeIn, while a Tab button is activated?

Heres the code:

```
$('ul.tab-buttons').each(function(){
  var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');


  $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
  $active.addClass('active');
  $content = $($active.attr('href'));


  $links.not($active).each(function () {
    $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
  });


  $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
    // Make the old tab inactive.
    $active.removeClass('active');
    $content.hide();

    $active = $(this);
    $content = $($(this).attr('href'));


    $active.addClass('active');
    $content.fadeIn();

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

I really cant get it. And its really important, because if someone clicks in the active button, the fadeIn starts over again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try with conditional inside `on();`, something like this:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('active') === false){
  // all your previous code 
  // Make the old tab inactive.
     $active.removeClass('active');
     $content.hide(); 
     ...
}
```

Haven't tried it though.

Comment: Hmm, thanks but I tried and didnt worked. I thought it will be easy, but Im getting insane.

Comment: Alright. meanwhile, I found a solution throw CSS (I was only focus in Jquery). So, I just implemented on the active CSS class:   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default; So, for me, mission accomplished :)